# print function name pass in llvm

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'd like to insert a function call (printf) in the first basic block of every function, which prints the function name. Please be specific how can I do that. The difficult part is that I don't know how to pass the function name as a parameter to printf.

Comment: can you tell me how are you extracting function name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward: you will need to grab the name of the function, create ConstantArray in your module (check ConstantArray::get() method described e.g. in http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ConstantArray.html) containing the name of your function and pass this array to printf() call.